# Any more+comparitive+than

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, comparatives, negative-polarity-items

I heard a person saying, “That place is not any more riskier than this place”. (And it wasn’t about time- like how it has changed from earlier to now) I thought it’s grammatically incorrect to say so.

*Anymore* can refer to any longer as in “I was doing it but I am not doing it anymore”, or it can be *any more* with a space like “some more” as in “I have already eaten so much. I do not need any more of it”

But in the context I mentioned earlier it is not about time.

And *riskier* is already a comparitive and adding *more* before that makes it incorrect.

This is what I feel but I am looking for an expert answer to know if I am right and if yes, I am looking for a solid explanation as to why it is incorrect.

Comment: (a) the string _not any more riskier than_ is ungrammatical. It should be either _not any more risky than_ or _not any riskier than_, but not both. (b) never mind the _any more_; it's a negative polarity item, but as you point out the problem doesn't have to do with negation particularly.

Comment: Beyond the correctness matter of double comparatives being forbidden in English, a simpler way to say it is that that place is no riskier than this one.

Comment: This is indeed ungrammatical, but don’t think that means you won’t hear native speakers say it. They’ll probably not write it, but double comparatives are fairly common in impromptu speech. I have a colleague at work (a native speaker) who for some reason is always getting nouns and adjectives mixed up after _so_, so she says things like, “That’s so much strange!” instead of “That’s so strange!”. Completely ungrammatical, but high-frequent from her…

Answer (score 1):

John Lawler wrote in a comment:

> (a) the string *not any more riskier than* is ungrammatical. It should be either *not any more risky than* or *not any riskier than*, but not both. (b) never mind the *any more*; it's a negative polarity item, but as you point out the problem doesn't have to do with negation particularly.